# JBoss AS7 remote debugging and deploying

Tags: jboss7.x

I install JBoss AS on VPS. I forward ports and I can access to server form my local machine. It is any possibility to add this server to Eclipse IDE? 
I expect the same effect debugging and deploying to remote instance of jboss.

Best regards

Comment: Do you try eclipse jboss tools plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Do you try eclipse jboss tools plugin?

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/121986#.ULYXteMSXk4

OK.

Look at this tutorial from point 5.
http://www.glxn.net/seam-maven-refimpl/doc/tutorial/02-eclipse.html

Comment: I installed it, but I am not sure how to use it at all.

Comment: OK.

Look at this tutorial from point 5. http://www.glxn.net/seam-maven-refimpl/doc/tutorial/02-eclipse.html

Comment: This tutorial shows how to configure local server. It is easy for me. I have my laptop with eclipse and remote server with jboss. I would like to "connect" to remote jboss from eclipse. I can not find solution for my problem in tutorial which you send ;/

Comment: just replace the localhost or what ever with your remote ip

Comment: Are you sure? Did you test it? I can not manage this task. I will need install jboss localy for testing and remote for final.

Comment: There is checkbox in point 6. Do not check it so that you can give in the next window your remote server settings